# Modal form button location is disturbed after putting form tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is one of a modal form in my homepage but after applying the form tags the location of buttons got disturbed. if I close the form tag after signup button then the location is perfect but then signup buttons also works as login button.

```html
<div id="ven_myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" id="ven_cont">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <?php $error="" ;?>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="ven_outerbox">


        <?php echo form_open(base_url( 'Login/vendor'));?>

        <input type="email" name="email" id="ven_box2" required="true" placeholder="Email"></input>
        </br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="ven_box3" required="true" minlength="6" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" name="ven_login_button" id="ven_login_button">Login</button>
        <?php echo form_close();?>
        <button name="ven_reg_button" id="ven_reg_button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ven_myModal1">Signup</button>


        <p class="forgot pull-left"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
        </p>

      </div>


      <div class="modal-footer">


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `type="button"` to `<button name="ven_reg_button"`

Comment: the actual position of login and signup button is horizontally aligned. but after closing form tag before signup button the signup button moves down a line

Comment: thanks bro its working

Comment: Feel free to close the question